# How to to read OpenCV image from the current working dir using VSCode and C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am currently setting up VS Code to be able to run cpp files. Now I have encountered an obstacle: I don't know how to change the setting which would allow me to read OpenCV images from 'src/' directory. Currently if I want to read images, I have to place them in the 'build' directory. When I was using Clion, changing this option was quite easy, <Run ---> edit configurations ---> Working directory: > and that's it, but I can't seem to find a way to do the same with the VS Code.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the difference but here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_opencv)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the src images because the location from where you execute the binary does not find the images. This is due to relative pathing and searching the current dir (**/build).

Here is how I would solve the situation and how I setup my CMakelists. The snippet below shows the 'cmake ..' call creating some additional DIRS.

```
#Project name
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project (myProject LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

# Include all necessary DIRS
include_directories(include)
include_directories(/usr/include)

# Get srcs files
file(GLOB SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

# Make bin dir
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY build/bin)

# Make resource dir
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY build/resources)

# Suppose you wanted to add an images folder specifically..
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY build/bin/resources/images)
```

At the root of my cmake tree, I keep an additional folder for images. This is the 'image archive' I'll call it. I keep everything there. When I want to load specific images/configs/anything, I'll copy the files(s) from the root/archive to the root/build/bin/** location.

The way you access the information will be based on if you use relative or absolute pathing. I prefer to almost ALWAYS use relative pathing in order to keep projects modular and running cross platform or system to system.

suppose your .exe is in /build/bin/myApp.exe
suppose the img is at /build/resources/imgs/myImage1.png

call your open file command as follows `../resources/imgs/myImage1.png`

The same can be done if you want to go back to your src dir

```
../src/*.png
```

TLDR: You are using relative paths and the executable and images are not in the same directory

Comment: But that means that I still need to copy files. What if I don't want to copy anything, and want only to read images from the same path that my main.cpp files exists?

Comment: Then you have to change your source code calls accessing the images. Suppose the call is open(myImg.png) the new call should be: open(../src/myImg.png)

Comment: But why can I do that on Clion? I just changed the working directory and then I could read images without the need of declaring relative path to build, for example: if image is in the same dir as main.cpp I can just do imread(image_path).

Comment: Clion is likely moving the PWD of the executable to where you specify it. You can do the same on for vsCode either by: Modify your CMake to still use the build folder, but deploy the binary to ../src. Or you can manually cut/paste the binary into the src DIR